# How to change a FormatedTextField mask dynamically?

Tags: java, swing

So I have this FormatedTextField

```
JFormattedTextField myFtf = new JFormattedTextField();
```

which has the following mask, placed in my application constructor

```
try {
    myFtf.setFormatterFactory(
        new DefaultFormatterFactory(
           new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##")));
} catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, I have a two radio buttons, which should be changing the mask formatter in `myFtf`.

I have tried the following:

```
private radioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    try {
        myFtf.setFormatterFactory(
            new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                                 

private void radioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
    try {
        myFtf.setFormatterFactory(
            new DefaultFormatterFactory(
               new MaskFormatter("##.###.###/####-##")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Which works fine, until I try to change their masks *when there is input within the text field*. In case there is, it doesn't change the mask anymore. Here are a couple of prints:

---

OK scenario:

img a:
[image]

switching radio buttons gives me this:

img b:
[image]

---

Buggy scenario:

img c:
[image]

switching radio buttons gives me this:

img d:
[image]

I was expecting *img d* to be exactly like *img a*

---

**How can I dynamically change its mask correctly?**

Comment: What result were you expecting in the second scenario? The same as in the first?

Comment: @user1803551 yes, cleared boxes with no input and correct mask

Answer (score 2):

I got it working correctly! All I needed to do was adding a

```
myFtf.setValue(null);
```

after setting the new formatter factory. `myFtf.setText("")` wasn't working as expected, but it was a close shot! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your action listeners to this:

```
private radioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    try {
        myFtf.setFormatterFactory(
            new DefaultFormatterFactory(
                new MaskFormatter("###.###.###-##")));
        myFtf.setText("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}                                                 

private void radioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                      
    try {
        myFtf.setFormatterFactory(
            new DefaultFormatterFactory(
               new MaskFormatter("##.###.###/####-##")));
        myFtf.setText("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That should clear the text fields.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same behavior.